# Remove an item from a List ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a List of `Student`. Every time I click on the Delete link it removes the selected student from the list but if I repeat clicking the delete link for another record my list returns back to default initialize and then delete the new record is done. I know my problem is because I initialized my list in the controller's constructor. So where should I initialize my list that doesn't be reinitialized in postbacks?

```
List<Student> lst;
public HomeController()
{
   lst = new List<Student>
   {
       new Student {Id = 1, Name = "Name1"},
       new Student{Id = 2 , Name = "Name2"},
       new Student{Id = 3 , Name = "Name3"},
   };
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(lst);
}

public ActionResult Delete(int? i)
{
     var st = lst.Find(c=>c.Id==i);
     lst.Remove(st);
     return View("Index",lst);
}
```

And here is my View:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid silver">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Id
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete",new{i = item.Id})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Comment: `MVC` is stateless because `HTTP` is. Use session

Comment: Every time the page loads, it rebuilds the list. You need to make it a static variable or use something like a session variable or database if you need it to maintain state between requests.

Comment: Make `lst` static and provide the values outside the constructor. Also, while it wouldn't throw an error, you have a comma after your last list item.

Comment: @MikeDebela Is ASP.NET Webforms also stateless? Should I use sessions for this example in ASP.NET Webforms too?

Comment: @user5032790 No. ASP.NET Webforms have the concept of `ViewState`.

Comment: @MikeDebela But I did this example in Webforms and again my list was empty in postbacks!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Session for that.

For example, add this property to controller:

```
public List<Student> Students
{
   get
   {
       if(Session["Students"] == null)
       {
           Session["Students"] = new List<Student>
           {
               new Student {Id = 1, Name = "Name1"},
               new Student{Id = 2 , Name = "Name2"},
               new Student{Id = 3 , Name = "Name3"},
           };
       }
       return Session["Students"] as List<Student>;
   }
   set
   {
       Session["Students"] = value;
   }
}
```

and use it in your Delete action:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? i)
{
     var st = Students.Find(c=>c.Id==i);
     Students.Remove(st);
     return View("Index",lst);
}
```

Comment: Just a question:  Is ASP.NET Webforms also stateless? Should I use sessions for this example in ASP.NET Webforms too?

Comment: @user5032790 In Web forms you can use Sessions and also ViewState. But ViewState is preserved in html page as hidden field, so if user will refresh or leaves the page, ViewState will be lost.

Comment: My question is:  is ASP.NET Webforms also stateless or not?

Comment: Asp.net web forms is not stateless but Http protocol is (REST design).