# Remove an item from a List ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following code:

```
private List<Student> students;

public List<Student> Collection()
{
    students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student {Id = 1, Name = "Name1"},
        new Student {Id = 2, Name = "Name2"},
        new Student {Id = 3, Name = "Name3"},
    };
    return students;   
}

protected void LinkButton1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    var st = students.Find(c => c.Id == int.Parse(s));
    students.Remove(st);
    repeater.DataBind();
}
```

In the `LinkButton1_OnClick` event the `students` is null. Why? I have [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530831/remove-an-item-from-a-list-asp-net-mvc) in ASP.NET MVC and I've been told that MVC is stateless and I should use `session`. **My question: is ASP.NET Webforms is stateless too?** This program works by using Sessions but if ASP.NET Webforms is not stateless why I should use Sessions for this example?

Comment: Where do you call Collection?

Comment: @MarcusH...In repeater's ObjectDataSource.

Comment: The `LinkButton1_OnClick` call happens on a postback event, where `IsPostBack == true`, so your list is not actually being populated on a postback event.

Comment: @VitorRigoni just tell me please ASP.NET Webforms is stateless or not? I ask this question from 4-5 people and each one give me a different answer. Where can I find a reference about this?

Answer (score 2):

The entire web is stateless unless you do something to add state. In Web Forms you can use [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or Session. Or you can postback the data necessary for your list, or requery it from the database.

Note that it's not recommended to use ViewState as it greatly increases the size of your requests and responses.

Using ViewState codewise is similar to Session.

```
// add to viewstate
List<Student> students = Collection();
ViewState["students"] = students;

// later we can retrieve them
// cast is necessary because it comes back from the ViewState as an object
List<Student> students = (List<Student>)ViewState["students"];
```

Keep in mind that in Web Forms, each time the page is accessed it creates a new instance of your page class. So fields and properties will lose their values that you had set them to.

Comment: Thanks. So ASP.NET Webforms is stateless too and I have to use Sessions or ViewState here? isn't there any other way?

Comment: @user5032790 Yeah, you can retrieve the value from the database every time. Or cache commonly used data. Or store data in the form and re-retrieve it on postback. Which you choose depends on who the data comes from and how large it is.

Comment: Thanks again. I just read in one answer which said ASP.NET MVC is stateless but ASP.NET Webforms not. This is what I thought that I shouldn't use Sessions here.

Comment: @user5032790 Like I said *all* of the web is stateless unless you do something to add state. In the case of Web Forms, you can use ViewState, which is probably why they said it's stateful. Note however that ViewState isn't recommended by most people (indeed, software developers are tending to use MVC instead of Web Forms anyways).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP protocol is stateless where response is created with only the information contained in request. To be able to use the advantages of a stateful protocol, with ASP.NET Webforms, concepts like `Postback` is introduced. Both protocols have advantages and disadvantages. But in both ways you should handle your variables that you want to keep between responses and requests manually.

[Stateful-stateless](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101337/whats-the-difference-between-stateful-and-stateless)

[Web Forms - MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please show me how I can do this without sessions and just by using concepts like Postback as you said?

Comment: Postback is used to catch the state of the page. It will not help you to keep your variables. You must store your variable in the memory yourself. See [the page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and than you should decide which state is more convenient for you to store your variables.

Answer (score 0):

All HTTP protocol are stateless .So to save data in asp.net use

1. Session State
2. Application State
3. Cookie

Cookies are convenient  as it store data on browser on client machine.There are some security issue  as cookie stores data in plan text.That can be overcome by encrypting and decrypting the cookie.

You can a save data in cookie if you do not use session

```
 private List<Student> students;

        public List<Student> Collection()
        {
            students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student {Id = 1, Name = "Name1"},
        new Student {Id = 2, Name = "Name2"},
        new Student {Id = 3, Name = "Name3"},
    };
            return students;
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Student> students = Collection();
           // ViewState["students"] = students;
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer=new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = serializer.Serialize(students);
            // Set the cookie value.
            myCookie.Value = data;
            // Set the cookie expiration date.
            myCookie.Expires = now.AddHours(1);

            // Add the cookie.
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

            //Response.Write("<p> The cookie has been written.");
        }
```

and to retrieve data

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];
            IList<Student> persons = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                .Deserialize<IList<Student>>(myCookie.Value);

        }
```